# tar syntax for copying the name of folders to tar.gz filaname

Tags: tar

I have this script for compressing multiple directories with files:

for file in /users/dpinili/accessions/CXrice/cx*

> do
>
> > tar -zcvf (basename "$file").tar.gz $file
> >
> > wait
> >
> > rm -r $file
> >
> > wait
>
> done

The interface says syntax error on "(basename "$file").tar.gz". I just want to make the name of tar.gz file similar to the file it is compressing. How can I do this?
Hope you can help me. Thank yoou very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with [bash command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) instead of tar. You can fix your syntax error just by adding a dollar sign before your left parenthesis like so:

```
tar -zcvf $(basename "$file").tar.gz $file
```